# Installing TensorFlow on M1 Mac

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I can't install TensorFlow. The main error I get is mach-o, but wrong architecture.

Some routes I have gone down...

1. install from releases on apple GitHub     error is:- mach-o, but wrong architecture
2. install using /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/master/scripts/download_and_install.sh)" -No module found
3. I have regular anaconda so none of those methods work. You need mini-forge. I am not willing to downgrade to a lighter version

I am pretty certain the root of the problem is that my default python is an anaconda version.
I tried to reset my default to python3.8 that I downloaded from the web using

ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python error: permission denied

so try to grant permission
sudo chown -R "$myname":admin /usr/local error: operation denied

Any insight?

Comment: If you really had no choice, you could try Google Collaboratory as an alternative.

Comment: you could also try uninstalling conda and python, and redownload from apple sources

Comment: You should not use `ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python`, link to python3 instead and try to install using python3.

Comment: Tensorflow cannot fully support MAC M1. Reading the thread https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44751#issuecomment-764841687

Comment: Have you tried the instructions in [this](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/153) repo? If you choose to use `brew`, [this comment](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/153#issuecomment-847161119) further down might help.